# mysql crosstab with month columns and multiple field rows

Tags: php, mysql

Creating monthly sales summary for different products.  Zane Bien post here very helpful in creating query to produce one row for a single product:

```
Income Source  Jan   Feb   Mar   --  Total  Pct  
Report Fees    11285 12745 17980 ... 236970 95.9954
```

Here is that query:

```
SELECT "Report Fees" AS `Income Source`, 
SUM( IF( MONTH( b.ord_billed_time ) =1, b.ord_fee_report, 0 ) ) AS Jan, 
SUM( IF( MONTH( b.ord_billed_time ) =2, b.ord_fee_report, 0 ) ) AS Feb, 
SUM( IF( MONTH( b.ord_billed_time ) =3, b.ord_fee_report, 0 ) ) AS Mar, 
"..." AS `--` , 
SUM( b.ord_fee_report ) AS Total, 
AVG( b.ord_fee_report / b.ord_fee_total ) *100 AS Pct
FROM orders b
WHERE b.ord_billed_time IS NOT NULL 
AND b.ord_cancelled_time IS NULL 
AND b.ord_fee_report IS NOT NULL 
AND year( b.ord_billed_time ) = 2012
AND b.clientID = 8
```

Is there a way to expand this single query so that I get 8 rows, one for each different income type, and a "grand total" line?  Something like this:

```
Income Source  Jan   Feb   Mar   --  Total  Pct  
Report Fees    11285 12745 17980 ... 236970 95.9954
Income Type2    5401  3320  1394 ...  13456  0.321
Income Type3      98   421    14 ...   1102  0.001
...
Total         333333 22222 11111 ... 9999999 100.0
```

The income types are stored in the orders table in separate columns: ord_fee_x, ord_fee_y, ord_fee_z, etc.

Right now I'm running 8 queries and loading results into an array, then displaying from that array.  Just seems more efficient to get data all at one time and display row by row as returned.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible through the `UNION` operation. Ideally, you should use `UNION ALL` for your situation as it appears that your queries will produce unique results based off the custom calculations for each income source. `UNION ALL` will include all rows which is arguably faster in comparison to `UNION`, which excludes duplicate rows.

In other words:

```
(SELECT "Report Fees" AS `Income Source`, 
SUM( IF( MONTH( b.ord_billed_time ) =1, b.ord_fee_report, 0 ) ) AS Jan, 
SUM( IF( MONTH( b.ord_billed_time ) =2, b.ord_fee_report, 0 ) ) AS Feb, 
SUM( IF( MONTH( b.ord_billed_time ) =3, b.ord_fee_report, 0 ) ) AS Mar, 
"..." AS `--` , 
SUM( b.ord_fee_report ) AS Total, 
AVG( b.ord_fee_report / b.ord_fee_total ) *100 AS Pct
FROM orders b
WHERE b.ord_billed_time IS NOT NULL 
AND b.ord_cancelled_time IS NULL 
AND b.ord_fee_report IS NOT NULL 
AND year( b.ord_billed_time ) = 2012
AND b.clientID = 8)
UNION ALL
(... query 2 ...)
UNION ALL
(... query 3 ...)
```

and so forth.

**Reference**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Daniel.
I was hoping for a CASE or similar solution that would be more code efficient, but guess that's not an option.  Will save me creating a bunch of arrays, though.
Bruce

Comment: When you want to give thanks or more information, you should use comments - not answers.

Comment: Damiqib: Sorry, new to this site.  Will do that in future.